# HTTPS POST in C#, Winforms (Stream Writer, HttpWebResponse, HttpWebRequest)

Tags: c#, winforms, post, https

**UPDATE: I am trying to POST data to https URI. The POST works for HTTP but it fails for HTTPS uri**

---

Hi I am creating a c# winforms exe to post data to a website. The code is below. The issue is, the stream duplicates my post data..

eg: suppose I want to post this -> `username=bob`

Then when I check the traffic, what is actually sent is, `username=bobusername=bob`

See? It duplicates, it adds the same line once more to the end of the buffer and sends it.

I am going crazy trying to find the issue from two days.. Can any body solve this or give me some hints please? thank you..

(content length is correctly set to 12, but it sends 24 bytes, after appending same data once again to the tail of buffer)

There are the headers

```
POST /login/ HTTP/1.0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: abc.test.com
Content-Length: 12

username=bobusername=bob
-
```

This is the code I am currently using

```
string post_data = "username=bob";
string uri = "https://abc.test.com/login/";

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)
WebRequest.Create(uri); 
request.KeepAlive = false;
request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
request.Method = "POST";

byte[] postBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(post_data);

request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;

Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();

requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);

MessageBox.Show(postBytes.Length.ToString());
requestStream.Close();

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
string tmp = sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
```

I put a breakpoint on line `byte[] postBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(post_data);` and `postBytes` contains the correct data... but it gets output twice.

Why is this happening? I hope I am clear..

Answer (score 2):

I tried out your code and it seemed to work as expected (sent a HTTP Post with a 12byte payload) after I changed the host in the URI to something that was addressable (used http://adsf.com/login). Here's the trace from wireshark:

[image: Wireshark trace]

You might try out the URI I used to see what you get, this will at least rule out your computer or code as possible sources of the problem. If the problem disappears when using a different URI then the problem might be between your network equipment and the web server (reverse-proxy configuration, webserver configuration, network switch configuration, etc).

Comment: Hi Darwyn, thank you for your time and help.. I tried this new URI, and noted that, now my exe sends correct data.. BUT the interesting thing i found is, this fails only when its HTTPS request.. for HTTP links its snding the buff one tiem only.. So anybody any idea why for HTTPS (secure) connection the data is duplicated? I am trying to send to an HTTPS site.. (edited my tquestion now)

Comment: it fails for HTTPS, it works for HTTP. I want to post to HTTPS URI unfortunately...

Answer (score 1):

You can try to get more information by setting trace configuration as described in this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty48b824%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). When I tried your code, I get the following output:

```
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [2324] Data from ConnectStream#26756241::Write
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [2324] 00000000 : 75 73 65 72 6E 61 6D 65-3D 62 6F 62             : username=bob
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [2324] Exiting ConnectStream#26756241::Write()
```

Looks like data is correctly written to the ConnectStream. Something wrong somewhere else?

And don't forget to close the **WebResponse** object.

Comment: hi jiaji wu, thank you for ur time and help. I tried closing webresponse. But its still sending duplicate. Yes, Something is wrong somewhee else..